# Почему нужна запятая

Tags: пунктуация

Василий Петрович давно уехал из захолустного провинциального городка (1) _ и (2) _ когда спустя много лет оказался в родных краях, он не узнал его (3) _ на месте старых 
(4) _ и обветшалых жилых домов (5) _ и других зданий стояли современные строения

Почему на месте (1) нужна запятая, а на месте (5) нет ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Почему на месте (1) нужна запятая

Эта запятая соединяет части сложносочинённого предложения:

***Василий Петрович*** давно **уехал** из захолустного провинциального городка, **и** <…> **он не узнал...**

> а на месте (5) нет ?

А эта запятая соединяет однородные определения:

*…на месте (каком?) **домов и  зданий**.*